# How to achieve toon shading like this in eevee?

Tags: materials, eevee-render-engine, toon-shading

Alright, this has been asked before but I haven't found a satisfactory answer. Is there a good **handdrawn toon shader** in existence for eevee? Here's the look Im going for - toon, painted, around the edges but **affected by the color of light directed on it**

[image]

[image]

This is from the game Ooblets. So far, Ive tried using a standard toon shader https://gumroad.com/l/gkExH and feeding in painted textures. The issue is that this shader isn't affected by color of light, and the "steps" in separating the colors of the toon shader are hard lines, not fuzzy handdrawn.

**Hard steps:**

[image]

**Soft, handdrawn steps:**

[image]

How can this be achieved? Does this exist?

Here's what Im getting at. After painting the textures, the effect works with a generic toon shader in full lighting:

[image]

The problem is, it does not react to color or strength of lighting, beyond the banding. So with a dark blue light (for nighttime) we get this:

[image]

The only solution I can think of is just keeping the lighting constant to achieve the banding, then just paint the textures per my lighting setup? This feels too static.

Comment: This doesn't look like toon shading at all. It seems to be regular shading on low-poly assets with smooth shading.

Comment: @metaphor_set Can you explain what you mean by regular shading? Because if I use a normal diffuse shader smooth shaded Im not going to get those hand painted steps like the tree demonstrates

Comment: There is a VERY high amount of post-processing going on in these images (color correction, vignette, bloom, particles, etc.) and it looks like textures are, well, hand painted. so your best bet is to paint textures directly on the assets

Comment: @Gorgious See my edit

Comment: @metaphor_set see my edit

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of components at play to achieve the unique artwork you posted as a reference. For this reason, there is no silver bullet answer on how to recreate a 100% match. That said if you follow [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/TpWI2rU8iF0?t=426) it will teach you how to control the propagation of light on meshes, which should be a good start. The basic setup is to use a **Diffuse BSDF** and plug it in the **Fac** of a **ColorRamp**.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the tutorial link. See my edit - the banding seems to be fine with a lowpoly smooth shaded model. Its the reaction to light that is problematic

Comment: I think it would be worth posting a screenshot of your material node graph.